# Pausing and resuming a concurrent database update queue

Tags: java, database, asynchronous, concurrency, queue

I have a class `DatabaseQueue` which asynchronously runs SQLite updates that it takes from a `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

I implemented a pausing mechanism for this class which should ideally stop the execution of the queue as soon as possible and then wait for it to be unpaused before executing more queries.

I'm very new to concurrent programming but I managed to get this working using multiple `ReentrantLock`'s and `Condition`'s. This seems very verbose and clumsy though, especially with all the lock()'s and unlock()'s.

In addition to this, I also don't like how I have to execute an additional dummy query just to get the executor thread to continue its loop. What would be a better way to implement this?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class DatabaseQueue {

    private static final LinkedBlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private static final QueueExecutor executor = new QueueExecutor();

    private static boolean locked = false;
    private static ReentrantLock lockAttempted = new ReentrantLock();
    private static ReentrantLock lockAcquired = new ReentrantLock();
    private static Condition attempted = lockAttempted.newCondition();
    private static Condition acquired = lockAcquired.newCondition();

    public static void start() {
        if (locked) {
            locked = false;
            lockAttempted.lock();
            attempted.signal(); //Signal to resume queue execution
            lockAttempted.unlock();
        } else {
            executor.start();
        }
    }

    public static void pause() {
        locked = true;
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            queue.add("SELECT 1");
        }
        lockAcquired.lock();
        acquired.awaitUninterruptibly(); //Wait for the lock to be acquired
        lockAcquired.unlock();
    }

    public static void queue(String update) {
        queue.add(update);
    }

    public static class QueueExecutor extends Thread {

        public QueueExecutor() {
            setName("Database Queue Executor");
            setDaemon(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Connection connection = Database.getConnection();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (locked) {
                        lockAcquired.lock();
                        acquired.signal(); //Signal that the lock has been acquired
                        lockAcquired.unlock();
                        lockAttempted.lock();
                        attempted.awaitUninterruptibly(); //Wait for the lock to be released
                        lockAttempted.unlock();
                    }
                    String update = queue.take();
                    connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(update);
                    Database.update(update);
                } catch (InterruptedException | SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Why are all your variables static? You [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7026507/3533380) use them.
2. You don't need that many locks. Actually, you need only 1 and a `AtomicBoolean` (`locked`).
3. I can't understand why you add `"SELECT 1"` if the `queue` is empty. That'll  waste some precious time.
4. I *think* as long as there's only 1 `QueueExecutor` you don't need to make the `queue` thread-safe.
5. You could execute your statements in batches but I'm not sure of the pros and cons.
6. Unless you 100% trust the user you should use `PreparedStatement`s but even if you do trust the user you still should use it as it will give you a speed (i.e. query execution) boost.
7. Wouldn't it be better to pass `Statement`s to `queue` instead of `String`? It would allow you to easily allow the user to use `PreparedStatement`s

Example implementation (not tested):

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class DatabaseQueue {

    private final Deque<PreparedStatement> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final QueueExecutor executor = new QueueExecutor();
    private final AtomicBoolean paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final Object object = new Object();

    public DatabaseQueue() {
        executor.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        if (!paused.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("DatabaseQueue wasn't paused");
        }

        executor.notify();
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (!paused.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("DatabaseQueue is already paused");
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        executor.shutdown();

        paused.set(false); // we want to execute all the statements before closing
        executor.notify();
    }

    public void queue(PreparedStatement statement) {
        queue.addLast(statement);

        if (!paused.get())
            executor.notify();
    }

    public PreparedStatement createStatement(String sql) throws SQLException {
        return Database.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    }

    class QueueExecutor extends Thread {
        private boolean shutdown = false;

        QueueExecutor() {
            setName("Database Queue Executor");
            setDaemon(true);
        }

        void shutdown() {
            shutdown = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // even if we should shutdown we first should execute all the statements
            do {
                if (paused.get() || queue.isEmpty()) {

                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {
                    PreparedStatement statement = queue.removeFirst();

                    if (!paused.get())
                        statement.execute();
                    else
                        queue.addFirst(statement);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (!shutdown || !queue.isEmpty());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: queue.take() will pause execution of the thread until a query is available. So, if the queue is first empty, then paused, then a statement is queued, it will execute regardless of being paused. So I'm executing "SELECT 1" to force it to reach the locking code. Also could you please explain how I could utilize just one AtomicBoolean to achieve the same effect?

Comment: @kmecpp I added example code. I did not test it but it looks reasonable to me

Answer (score 2):

All the points by @Mibac are valid.

Naming is also very important.  You have the `locked` variable, but the function that controls it is `pause()`, which made your code confusing.  It would have been better if the variable was also named `paused`.  @Mibac did this renaming in his code, but did not mention it explicitly.

`locked` was not declared as `volatile`, so it's not thread-safe.  Or as @Mibac suggested, it would be even clearer to use an `AtomicBoolean`.

But instead of you using a boolean, I think it's better to use something which is blocking for the pause condition.  That way the continuous loop in the writer thread can simply block-wait on 1) a new element in the queue and 2) the pause condition, in that order.  Then it writes the element to DB.  And then it's back to the start of the while loop waiting again on 1) and 2).

You could use for example [Semaphore](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) with one permit as the blocking condition for 2).  For example:

```
while (...) {
    element = queue.take(); // blocking

    semaphore.acquire();  // blocking
    semaphore.release(); 

    writeToDB(element);
}
```

The semaphore permit is released right after it's acquired since it's just used as a blocking mechanism to wait if another thread requests a pause.  Maybe there is a cleaner way to do this with a CyclicBarrier, CountDownLatch or Phaser.  I think it's cleaner to use one those constructs which blocks (including Semaphore) rather than just a boolean flag.  A Lock might not work because it might require that `.lock()` and `.unlock()` be called from the same thread.

And for pausing and resuming from other threads:

```
public void pause() {
    if (semaphore.availablePermits() == 1) {
        semaphore.acquire(); // blocking, but should never happen
    }
}

public void resume() {
    semaphore.release();
}
```

Note here that I only acquire a permit if no other thread has already requested a pause.  This basically means that there can only be one pause even if there are requests from many threads. Calling `semaphore.release()` when there is no permit to release does nothing bad.  `semaphore.acquire()` can be a blocking call, but in this setup it should only block for an infinitesimally small time in the rare case where the writer thread would be calling acquire() at the same time, but that is followed immediately by release().